# Bind data from JSON response to listbox

Tags: c#, json, data-binding

I am currently working on a map function which requires me to display the data from the extracted JSON Response. This is the part of the class I get from my JSON response. I wish to extract 'text' from the JSON Response to display in the listbox.

```
 public class Attributes
    {
        public double length { get; set; }
        public double time { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; } //Want to display in listbox
        public long ETA { get; set; }
        public string maneuverType { get; set; }
    }

    public class rootobject
    {
        public Attribute attributes { get; set; }
        public string compressedGeometry { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried learning online but the data in the example are all hard-coded. Example of what I mean hard-coded:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample method in WS web service.

```
     [WebMethod]
    public rootobject GetData()
    {
        var rootObj = new rootobject()
        {
            attributes = new Attribute[2] { new Attribute() { text = "text 1" }, new Attribute() { text = "text 2" } },
            compressedGeometry = "geometry 1"
        };

        return rootObj;
    }
```

JavaScript code to pull data from service

```
var webMethod = "WS.asmx/GetData";
var parameters = "";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: webMethod,
data: parameters,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {
    $("#sel").html(msg.d);
    var index = 0;
    for (; index < msg.d.attributes.length; index++)
    {
        $("#sel").append("<option>" + msg.d.attributes[index].text + "<option>");
    }
},
error: function (e) {
    alert(e);
}
});
```

HTML for the drop down/ select

```
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Comment: Your class might have a typo error - As You have declared "Attribute" in your rootObject definition - which doesn't seems to be right. You can change Attributes class name to Attribute and above code will work for you.

Comment: Thx for pinpointing my typo to me. But the problem I am facing is that i have my JSON response and I want to extract the 'text' from the json response to display in listbox.

Comment: P.S the JSON response is derived from current location and final location.